# Minecraft Launcher re-compile

Tags: java, compilation, minecraft, launcher

I'm trying to make custom launcher to Minecraft. I just want it to download main jar file from my own server, nothing else. I decompiled one file ([Launcher.java](http://pastebin.com/NPL86cMZ)) and changed the download url from "https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/" to my own. The problem is, that when I try to re-compile it with javac -classpath launcher.jar launcher.java it throws 5 errors:

```
launcher.java:313: error: reference to listFiles is ambiguous, both method listFiles(FilenameFilter) in File and method listFiles(FileFilter) in File match File[] directories = objectsDir.listFiles(DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);

launcher.java:317: error: reference to listFiles is ambiguous, both method listFiles(FilenameFilter) in File and method listFiles(FileFilter) in File match File[] files = directory.listFiles(FileFileFilter.FILE);

launcher.java:409: error: reference to listFiles is ambiguous, both method listFiles(FilenameFilter) in File and method listFiles(FileFilter) in File match File[] directories = virtualsDir.listFiles(DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);

launcher.java:441: error: reference to listFiles is ambiguous, both method listFiles(FilenameFilter) in File and method listFiles(FileFilter) in File match File[] versions = root.listFiles(DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);

launcher.java:445: error: reference to listFiles is ambiguous, both method listFiles(FilenameFilter) in File and method listFiles(FileFilter) in File match File[] files = version.listFiles(FileFilterUtils.and(new IOFileFilter[] { new PrefixFileFilter(version.getName() + "-natives-"), ageFilter }));
```

Are there any way to do this? Don't mind my writing style, I tried to solve this whole night...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove launcher class from the JAR. I think there exists duplicate class there.

Comment: Did that, now it throws 8 errors... Those 5 old ones and 3 new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself! I needed to do this:

```
import java.io.FileFilter;
```

and then modify each error line from

```
File[] directories = objectsDir.listFiles(DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);
```

to this:

```
File[] directories = objectsDir.listFiles((FileFilter) DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);
```

and now everything is working.